# Strategy for a central Web API application to serve multiple .NET front-ends

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, architecture

I want to finally decouple as much as i can my existing ASP.NET MVC projects.

They use multiple approaches as the time went by and i was learning:

1. Standard MVC, controller actions return separate views to browser.
2. Controller actions returning FAT partialviews and jquery updating pages.
3. Controller actions returning just JSON/XML data and jquery does the job of updating the UI

Now i want to move on to more dynamic front-ends by using heavier javascript approaches, by putting libraries like Knockout,Angular,Backbone e.t.c into the game. But i also want to be flexible enough and fast, if i want to just return a ready partialview from my controller actions.

So i was thinking of centralising my business layer NOT in the form of having common projects in my MVC projects, BUT having a Central WEB API endpoint above my business layer and DAL which will serve my various front ends (it can be MVC, console app, informs e.t.c)

This:

> DAL -> Business Layer -> WEB API

After that i want to know how to connect to WEB API output from various points:

1. Pure JS: Directly from WEB Api endpoints with ajax calls

   **2. .NET apps (MVC,WinForms e.t.c): How exactly?**

*My question is mostly about #2 above. I want specific use cases on how to consume my central WEP API from within windows Forms or MVC controller actions*

Comment: Not sure what you mean. For #2 you can just use an HTTP client and make GET/POST/PUT/etc. requests to the web api. The use cases depend on your application. But, if you want to return partial views to the JS frontend then you indeed need to call the web api from the MVC backend.

Comment: By the way, what you're attempting here is called Service Oriented Architecture (SOA).

Comment: @MarcelN. So the answer would be that my approach fits a pattern and i would use httpclient to do it form .net and ajax calls from javascript? I would need examples on that to make sure my approach is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [Service Oriented Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture).

For #2, you have the following options to call RESTful services from a .NET client (be it ASP.NET MVC or WinForms):

1. [Using an HttpClient](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client).
2. Use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). This is a helper lib which covers most of the basic operations, including request/response serialization and deserialization. Note that in newer versions JSON.NET support has been removed (for some reason I'm not remembering now... anyway, it's in a Google Groups discussion).

Either way I recommend looking into the async/await pattern which HttpClient fully supports. It will make your life a lot easier, especially for the WinForms stuff.

About #1, there's nothing stopping you from having the JavaScript front-end calling into the Web API. Just be [careful with CORS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api), as I assume you might need it (by having multiple web clients, possibly deployed on different domains).